# JMeter If Controller condition is not reached?

Tags: jmeter, ruby-jmeter

I'm trying to create a test under a token-based authorization mechanism. Everything is almost working fine until the accesstoken is expired. Then I'm trying to refresh it, however it seems some piece of the test is not performed.

This is the Authorization dance:

> ```
>      foreach user in users.csv:
>      {
>          Get Authorization Code: Http sampler
>          Extract AuthzCode on ${authorizationcode}: JSON extractor
>          if ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}
>          {
>              Get Access Token: Http sampler
>              Extract AccessToken on ${accesstoken}: JSON extractor
>              Extract RefreshToken on ${refreshtoken}: JSON extractor
>              if ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}
>              {
>                  foreach data in data.csv
>                  {
>                      Send data in body: Http sampler
>                      if ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok} == false *******************
>                      {
>                          Extract error on ${expiredaccesstokenerror}: JSON extractor
>                          if (${expiredaccesstokenerror} == "expired_accesstoken")
>                          {
>                              Get new accessToken using ${refreshtoken}: Http Request
>                              Extract AccessToken on ${accesstoken}: JSON extractor
>                              Extract RefreshToken on ${refreshtoken}: JSON extractor
>                          }
>                      }
>                  }
>              }
>          }
>      }
> ```

Everything works fine until the **AccessToken** expires and server returns me this body:

```
{
    "error_description":"Access token expired",
    "suberror":"expired_accesstoken",
    "error":"invalid_grant"
}
```

[image]

After that, I'm expecting JMeter reach the inside `if controller` with `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok} == false` and then the next `if controller` with condition `${expiredaccesstokenerror} == "expired_accesstoken"`. However I'm not able to figure out why this code is not reached.

As you can see in the herewith image, I've implemented this process in JMeter as:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change your 2nd condition to:

```
"${expiredaccesstokenerror}" == "expired_accesstoken"
```

Mind quotation marks around the variable. If Controller's conditions are evaluated by JavaScript engine (Rhino or Nashorn) and if you compare something with string you'll get "blabla is not defined" exception. When it was about 2 boolean types (`${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` and `false`) - it was fine, but if you want to compare a JMeter Variable to some string - you need to explicitly cast the variable to string. See [How to Use JMeter's 'IF' Controller and get Pie](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) article for more details.

Few more tips:

- In every situation when JMeter test is not working as expected take a look into *jmeter.log* file
- If *jmeter.log* file doesn't contain anything suspicious - go for [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination.